# How can I access to Android file system (e.g. navigate a dir) and stream data through the browser without using an app?

Tags: browser, permissions, stream-processing

I'm trying to develop the client side application of a remote audio player. I developed the server side application but I'm lost on the android side.

I want to navigate all the files in the music directory, obtain a list stored in my android phone and send music data through wifi to my PC. Is this possible? Can I implement this without make an apposite app? How can I do this?

Comment: what is "apposite app"?

Comment: "A specific app that solve this". 
I want to this without an app